# Rails 6 secure cookie issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, session-cookies, spree

I installed spree ecommerce on ubuntu. Everyting was fine until i set https with ngnix. Now i can not login the app in production.

App works properly, then only problem with login and sign up.

If i set `config.force_ssl = true` i get to much redirect error.

any idea please. Thank you.

```
server {
  server_name test.shenanay.com;

  root /home/ubuntu/she/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://test.shenanay.com:3000;
    proxy_set_header origin 'https://test.shenanay.com';
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
  }

  # some other configuration

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.shenanay.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.shenanay.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = test.shenanay.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name test.shenanay.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

Answer (score 0):

this fixed the problem.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22965

Thanks.